# Kutaisi center to airport: early morning public transport?

Tags: airport-transfer, georgia-country

I have a 6 am flight out of Kutaisi, Georgia (KUT) on a Saturday.

Georgian Bus offers a connecting shuttle departing Kutaisi city center at 03:30 and arriving at the airport at 04:00, but this would mean both getting up at 3 in the morning and arriving *way* too early at the airport (it's a tiny, efficient airport with just the one flight leaving that early).

Will there be *marshrutky* or public buses from Kutaisi leaving early enough in the morning (~04:30-04:45) to get to the airport between 05:00 and 05:15 (45 minutes to an hour before departure)?

Comment: Taxis are very cheap in Georgia. If I remember correctly it was less than 10 euros to get to the airport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, there is no other public transport to the airport that early in the morning.**

The earliest *marshrutky* leave Kutaisi around 6:00 ([source](http://www.visitkutaisi.com/en/travel-kit)). The only option earlier is the Georgian Bus shuttle or a taxi.

Comment: The traditional disadvantage of low-cost flights is their inconvenient departure time :)

Answer (score 3):

[Georgian Bus company](http://www.georgianbus.com/) makes transfers from Kutaisi city to Kopitnari (Kutaisi airport) and vice versa. Usually they adjust the departure times to certain flights, so you'll probably be satisfied with their schedule, depending on your flight.

[image]

Also, when I was flying from Kutaisi in 2013 I used taxi-bus (marshrutka) Kutaisi-Samtredia which departs from Kutaisi Bus Station ([look](https://www.google.com.ua/maps/@42.2570622,42.6707007,3a,75y,132.77h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-8VimnBCDnUs%2FVwfSEpjaXUI%2FAAAAAAAAhR8%2F413BqVI7yXg3_N11KaYL-N7bnj2IZG34ACLIB!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2F-8VimnBCDnUs%2FVwfSEpjaXUI%2FAAAAAAAAhR8%2F413BqVI7yXg3_N11KaYL-N7bnj2IZG34ACLIB%2Fw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya320.3405-ro0-fo100%2F!7i8192!8i4096), [location](https://www.google.com.ua/maps/@42.2563772,42.6713872,18.04z)) regularly, however, you should drop off on the road, as taxi-bus doesn't stop directly at the airport.

[image]